# what Spark SQL is doing when below message shown

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark SQL and I try to run a query and notice that Spark SQL get stock for a very long time.

```
scala> spark.time(query.collect)
[Stage 169:===========>   (44 + 4) / 58][Stage 170:>               (0 + 0) / 58]
```

Does anyone know the expression like `169`,`(44 + 4) / 58` or `(0 + 0) / 58)` indicate?

Answer (score 3):

it indicates following thing

```
[Stage stageNo: (numCompletedTasks + numActiveTasks) / totalNumOfTasksInThisStage]
```

Each Spark Job, is divided into multiple stages, and each stage is again divided into multiple tasks.

In your case. It says,

```
Stage: 169 
Total Tasks: 58
Completed tasks: 44 
Active Tasks: 4 
Remaining Tasks: 10 (totalNumOfTasksInThisStage - (numCompletedTasks + numActiveTasks))
```

Comment: 44+4  != 58. i think there is something else

Comment: @Meeran0823 you are absolutely1 right `44+4 != 58` that's because `numCompletedTasks + numActiveTasks != totalNumOfTasksInThisStage`